# How to force MessageBox to display as top window

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc

I don't known how to explain what I mean.
I created a program (A), that shows a  MessageBox after a time out.

It only shows the MessageBox like I want, if my program (A) is activated. But when I'm working with another program (B) (my program - A - is not active), the MessageBox only appears in the task bar, like this:

[image]

I want to this:

[image]

Can anyone help me create a messageBox that will be top-most (what is the name of the method)?

Comment: `MB_SYSMODAL` perhaps? One of those flags does this, but I can't remember what there is off the top of my head.

Comment: look at model / non-model  this is the keyword you are looking for

Comment: Do you only care about showing it visible? Or do you want to stop the user from doing what they are doing until your dialog has done.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Pass  MB_APPLMODAL as argument with the messagebox function

For more details
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645505(VS.85).aspx

Comment: MB_APPLMODAL does not solve the problem. You are thinking of MB_SYSTEMMODAL instead.

Comment: I use MB_TOPMOST: MessageBox(NULL,L"TEXT", L"OK", MB_OK | MB_TOPMOST);

Answer (score 5):

I also find out my solution:

I can use:

MB_SETFOREGROUND   or

MB_TOPMOST   or

MB_SYSTEMMODAL

Comment: `MB_TASKMODAL` might be a "quieter" alternative to `MB_SYSTEMMODAL`.

Comment: hint for others: (from my experience) **`MB_SETFOREGROUND`** brings the message **to the foreground**, even if the application itself is not in foreground, so obviously here no `AllowSetForegroundWindow()` is necessary. The message box window **gets focus** too.  -  All this applies to **`MB_TOPMOST`** too, but in addition the message **remains in the foreground**, even if the user activates other windows afterwards.